# Nginx redirect mobile traffic to different pages on same url error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect mobile traffic using Nginx but I am still getting errors.

Here is what I put on `nginx.conf`:

```
map $geoip_country_code $preferred_upstream {
    default eu;
    US us;
}

map $geoip_country_code $preferred_upstream_mp {
    default eum;
    US usm;
}

upstream us {
    server unix:/path/us.sock;
}

upstream eu {
    server unix:/path/eu.sock;
}

upstream usm {
    server unix:/path/usm.sock;
}

upstream eum {
    server unix:/path/eum.sock;
}

server {
    ....
    location @fallback {
        # add trailing slash if url has no dot in it
        rewrite ^/([^\.]*[^/])$ /$1/ permanent;
        include     uwsgi_params;
        set $mobile_rewrite do_not_perform;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|webOS|Windows Phone)') {
            set $mobile_rewrite perform;
        }

        if ($mobile_rewrite = do_not_perform) {
            uwsgi_pass $preferred_upstream;
            break;
        }

        if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
            uwsgi_pass $preferred_upstream_mp;
            break;
        }

        .......        
    }
    ...
}
```

I have installed `ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module` and set the following up:

```
more_set_headers -s 200 'Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent';
```

It works from the beginning. But some times after it can not display right version to right device.

I don't know why. It probably has something wrong on cache setting? It sounds like nginx does not detect user agent but only provide a cache page.

Can someone help me with this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved. It is not about nginx but django cache. I just disable django memcached for my web app, then it works. Thanks for viewing and hope the post can help others.